# program doesn't start under IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Sorry, if this question has already solved but... I have a little simple currency convertor under asp.net. My program reads xml file with currencies with XmlTextReader method. Then when I run my site under visual studio in debug or release mode it works perfectly, but when I run it just under IIS all parsed data are zero or non-decimal. If I don't use Decimal.TryParse(x, out y) it shows me error: "Input string was not in a correct format." But I don't understand why it shows me error only if I run it under IIS and doesn't show me it under VS. I think somethig wrong with permissions but I don't know where I can find the solution. Here the part of my code:

```
reader.MoveToAttribute(0);
string s1 = reader.Value;
reader.MoveToAttribute(1);
decimal d1 = 0;
Decimal.TryParse(reader.Value, out d1);
reader.MoveToAttribute(2);
decimal d2 = 0;
Decimal.TryParse(reader.Value, out d2);
valutaList.Add(new list { Valuta = s1, Pokupka = d1, Prodaga = d2 });
reader.MoveToElement();
```

later added: 
my xml-file is in web. I partly solved task with globalization classes but I get numbers with point like ",". How can I change it to "."? I added this code:

```
 Decimal.TryParse(reader.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), out d1);
```

Comment: `Decimal.TryParse` returns a boolean. Maybe you should be checking for that: `If (Decimal.TryParse(reader.Value, out d1)) {/* parse was successful*/};`.

Comment: You can use [Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.100).aspx) to connect to a running IIS process and then use the debugger in Visual Studio to step through the code and figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: my suspicion is the xml file is not being read. You said it is an asp.net app, is it asp.net mvc? Did you put the file in the app_data folder?

Comment: my file is in web. I partly solved task with globalization classes but I get numbers with point like ",". How can I change it to "."? I added this code: Decimal.TryParse(reader.Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), out d1);